# Implicit conversion causes stack overflow

Tags: scala

The following code snippet worked perfectly, then after some code changes in different files, I've started getting stack overflows resulting from recursive invocation of the implicit conversion. Has this ever happened to anyone, and if so what's the fix.

```
implicit def comparable2ordered[A <: Comparable[_]](x: A): Ordered[A] =
new Ordered[A] with Proxy {
  val self = x

  def compare(y: A): Int = {
    self.compareTo(y)
  }
}
```

Comment: Some notes, though I'm not completely sure. Isn't it `A <: Comparable[A]`? You don't need to bind `x` for calling `compareTo` in the anonymous class, don't you?

Comment: DateTime implements Comparable as a raw type, and thus Comparable[A] doesn't compile

Comment: Just replace `Comparable[_]` with `Ordered[DateTime]` and rename `compareTo` to `compare`, since `Ordered` is a subclass of Comparable this is pretty compatible.

Comment: @user44242 - the first time you mention `DateTime` is in this comment. You should change your question to be more explicit about it because it's so central to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I think that the reason for your stack overflow is the usage of `[A <: Comparable[_]]`. The *existential type* means in practice that you cannot actually compare an `A` to anything. This means that the compiler is "selecting" the implicit conversion to re-invoke in the `self.compareTo` call (hence the recursion). You would see this if you used the compiler switch *-XprintTypes*

So what to do?

---

Consider the difference between an `Ordering` and an `Ordered`. There should be an implicit ordering for your type.

```
implicit def comp2ord[A <: Comparable[A]] = new Ordering[A] {
  def compare(x : A, y : A) = x compareTo y
}
```

And then a way of turning this ordering into an `Ordered`:

```
implicit def ordering2order[A : Ordering](x : A) = new Ordered[A] {
  def compare(y : A) = implicitly[Ordering[A]].compare(x, y)
}
```

Usage with no implicit ordering:

```
scala> val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
df: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f67a0200

scala> TreeSet(df.parse("2011-03-04"), df.parse("2010-05-06"))
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ord: Ordering[java.util.Date]
   TreeSet(df.parse("2011-03-04"), df.parse("2010-05-06"))
          ^
```

Now with an implicit ordering...

```
scala> implicit def comp2ord[A <: Comparable[A]] = new Ordering[A] {
 | def compare(x : A, y : A) = x compareTo y
 | }
comp2ord: [A <: java.lang.Comparable[A]]java.lang.Object with Ordering[A]

scala> TreeSet(df.parse("2011-03-04"), df.parse("2010-05-06"))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[java.util.Date] = TreeSet(Fri Mar 04 00:00:00 GMT 2011, Thu May 06 00:00:00 BST 2010)
```

Of course, you would **also need** an implicit conversion from an `Ordering` to an `Ordered` in order to take advantage of scala's comparisons via `<`, `>=` etc:

```
scala> implicit def ordering2order[A : Ordering](x : A) = new Ordered[A] {
 | def compare(y : A) = implicitly[Ordering[A]].compare(x, y)
 | }
ordering2order: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[A])java.lang.Object with Ordered[A]

scala> df.parse("2010-04-05") < df.parse("2009-01-01")
res2: Boolean = false
```

---

In the case that your type `A` is a Java class which implements the *raw-type* `Comparable`, you will have to provide an explicit conversion:

```
implicit def comp2ord(x : DateTime) = new Ordered[DateTime] {
  def compare(y : DateTime) = x compareTo y
}
```

Comment: My type is DateTime, which implements Comparable as a rawtype, what you suggested fails to compile in that case.

Comment: @user44242 - then maybe you should have put that bit in the question?

Comment: I have added to my answer; I think you will have to provide an explicit conversion for your `DateTime` type.

Comment: For future reference, you can go from Comparable[A] to Ordered[A] just by importing `scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered` as the solution above already exists in the scala libraries.